# Stop execution when close to maximum execution time

Tags: php

I'm creating a script which will undoubtedly exceed standard running times of 30 or 60 seconds. Is there a neat way I can limit the execution time of my script in seconds? So I can use the full amount of execution time.

One solution I have is to get the `ini_get('max_execution_time')`, get the server time as execution begins `$current_time`, and then end execution at `$current_time + ini_get('max_execution_time')`. Is anyone aware of a more elegant solution though? Which is PHP 5+ compatible.

The script is a combinational optimisation solver, hence the likelihood for long execution times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [set_time_limit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) function

```
bool set_time_limit ( int $seconds )
```

> Set the number of seconds a script is allowed to run. If this is
>   reached, the script returns a fatal error. The default limit is 30
>   seconds or, if it exists, the max_execution_time value defined in the
>   php.ini.